# Method to use horizontal columns for a TV Guide?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am making an EPG (Electronic Programme Guide) and I have the basic container set up to insert columns into to show channels. I have read online some methods that I could use but I'm not sure. One of the ones I was thinking about using was bootstrap framework.

I am trying to make something like this. The big container with all the horizontal rows in! All advice appreciated thank you! [image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the grid for that if you're using bootstrap. So something like the following.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1></div>
<div class="col-sm-3>
<div>Some Content</div>
<div>

<div class="col-sm-4>
<div>Some Content</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2>
<div>Some Content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Though this is only a way of formatting the layout of the page. Given that a guide like the image is dynamic this probably isn't ideal.